# Find a vector given certain criteria in R

Tags: r, vector

I was searching online if it is possible to create a vector given certain conditions, such as it must contain 2 and 6 but not 5 and 1, also that it is in a specific range (2 000 000-4 999 999), and also that it must be even.
I have genuinely no idea about how to give these commands to R even if I know the basic functions to create a vector.

Thanks in advance for your time and for the big help

Comment: what do you mean "must be pair"? could you show an example?

Comment: You can check `seq`. You have multiple ways to create an integer vector/sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
# create a sequence from 2000000 to 4999999
v <- 2e6:(5e6 - 1) 

# filter the sequence with given criteria
v[grepl("(2.*6)|(6.*2)", v) & !grepl("(1.*5)|(5.*1)", v)]
```

Comment: Really thankful for the help, I'll definitely implement your suggest and learn more about grepl!

Answer (score 0):

You can create it using "seq" function.

```
seq(from = 2, to = 7, by = 2) 
#> [1] 2 4 6
```

Then use "setdiff" function to remove specific values you dont need.

```
remove <- c(2)

#> a
 [1] 2 4 6
#> setdiff(a, remove)
[1] 4 6
```